# How to get a development branch from Visual Studio Bitbucket extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, bitbucket

I am very new to bitbucket extensions:

When I log on to bitbucket I see 
[image]

However when I go to bitbucket extension within Visual Studio I am seeing this:
[image]

Where in the world is the option to select the branch option in the extension!!

Comment: Which extension are you talking about? This one? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MistyK.VisualStudioBitbucketExtension

Comment: Yup, thats the extension I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone the repo first, and then you checkout a branch from your local clone.

Comment: I am sorry in advance if I am not asking the right question here..I cloned the repo and I see it on the local side.   On the local side I see on folder with the project name.   What I am trying to ask is I was expecting a "Development Folder" , "Master Folder" and a "Main" folder' and code under each of the folders.

Comment: That's a misunderstanding of how git works. The repo you cloned contains all three branches, but you can only have one at a time checked out as a working copy (the files you see in the folder with the project name). I don't know what git tool you're using, so I can't give you good advice about what to do next. If you're using Team Explorer in VS, you can open the repo and then hit the Branches button. If you're using the git command line, you can do `git branch --list`. In either case, you'll need to checkout the branch in order to work on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  You are right it was a misunderstanding on my part.  This link helped me understand a lot more:
https://saraford.net/2017/04/26/how-to-create-a-local-copy-of-a-remote-branch-in-visual-studio-116/

Comment: That blog post contains a fair amount of misinformation, but it will help you get the job done. Note that Team Explorer is just one UI over git, and not all UIs work the same; it may help you to do some more reading to understand the concepts. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 is very helpful in this regard, although it's long.